# Issue when building JHipster with Angular4 on Linux

Tags: linux, jenkins, jhipster

I am trying to build my application in server-side with Jenkins. When running the command: 
**sudo ./mvnw -Pprod package*
I have the following error message:

```
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (webpack build prod) @ timetrack ---
[INFO] Running 'yarn run webpack:prod' in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/timetrack-jh
[INFO] yarn run v1.2.1
[INFO] $ yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www
[ERROR] warning From Yarn 1.0 onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options to be forwarded. In a future version, any explicit "--" will be forwarded as-is to the scripts.
[ERROR] module.js:471
[ERROR]     throw err;
[ERROR]     ^
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Error: Cannot find module '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/timetrack-jh/webpack/webpack.prod.js'
[ERROR]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
[ERROR]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
[ERROR]     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
[ERROR]     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
[ERROR]     at requireConfig (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/timetrack-jh/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:97:18)
[ERROR]     at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/timetrack-jh/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:104:17
[ERROR]     at Array.forEach (native)
[ERROR]     at module.exports (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/timetrack-jh/node_modules/webpack/bin/convert-argv.js:102:15)
[ERROR]     at yargs.parse (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/timetrack-jh/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:171:41)
[ERROR]     at Object.Yargs.self.parse (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/timetrack-jh/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:533:18)
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------*
```

I have done the same building on my Windows machine and that is working correctly. Could some one help me on what is happening on Linux system?

Linux version: Linux version 4.10.0-37-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-022) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170406 (Ubuntu 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) ) #41-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 6 20:20:00 UTC 2017

Thanks in advance,

-Rod

After some dealing I solved the problem above, but it persists having a new error message that follows (only on Linux, Windows is running well):

```
[INFO] Installed Yarn locally.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (yarn install) @ timetrack ---
[INFO] Running 'yarn install' in /home/rodrigo/test/TimeTrack
[INFO] yarn install v1.2.1
[INFO] [1/5] Validating package.json...
[INFO] [2/5] Resolving packages...
[INFO] [3/5] Fetching packages...
[INFO] info fsevents@1.1.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this modul                       e.
[INFO] info "fsevents@1.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility                        check. Excluding it from installation.
[INFO] [4/5] Linking dependencies...
[ERROR] warning "bootstrap@4.0.0-beta" has unmet peer dependency "popper.js@^1.1                       1.0".
[ERROR] warning "@schematics/angular@0.0.49" has incorrect peer dependency "@ang                       ular-devkit/schematics@0.0.34".
[ERROR] warning "license-webpack-plugin@1.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpac                       k-sources@>=1.0.0".
[INFO] [5/5] Building fresh packages...
[INFO] Done in 40.25s.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (webpack build prod) @ timetrack ---
[INFO] Running 'yarn run webpack:prod' in /home/rodrigo/test/TimeTrack
[INFO] yarn run v1.2.1
[INFO] $ yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www
[ERROR] warning From Yarn 1.0 onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options to                        be forwarded. In a future version, any explicit "--" will be forwarded as-is to                        the scripts.
[INFO]
[INFO] <--- Last few GCs --->
[INFO]
[INFO]       28 ms: Mark-sweep 1.4 (5.5) -> 1.3 (5.5) MB, 1.2 / 0.0 ms [allocati                       on failure] [GC in old space requested].
[INFO]       29 ms: Mark-sweep 1.3 (5.5) -> 1.3 (5.5) MB, 1.2 / 0.0 ms [allocati                       on failure] [GC in old space requested].
[INFO]       30 ms: Mark-sweep 1.3 (5.5) -> 1.3 (5.5) MB, 1.2 / 0.0 ms [allocati                       on failure] [GC in old space requested].
[INFO]       32 ms: Mark-sweep 1.3 (5.5) -> 1.3 (4.5) MB, 1.2 / 0.0 ms [last res                       ort gc].
[INFO]       33 ms: Mark-sweep 1.3 (4.5) -> 1.3 (4.5) MB, 1.2 / 0.0 ms [last res                       ort gc].
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] <--- JS stacktrace --->
[INFO]
[INFO] ==== JS stack trace =========================================
[INFO]
[INFO] Security context: 0x3957b609 <JS Object>
[INFO]     1: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [fs.js:10] [pc=0x29d1d25d] (t                       his=0x395081d9 <undefined>,exports=0x3d777f45 <an Object with map 0x4e409cad>,re                       quire=0x39585bf1 <JS Function NativeModule.require (SharedFunctionInfo 0x3958425                       d)>,module=0x3d777f11 <a NativeModule with map 0x4e40e2a1>,__filename=0x3d777f31                        <String[5]: fs.js>,__dirname=0x395081d9 <undefined>)
[INFO]     2: arguments adaptor frame: 4-...
[INFO]
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out                        of memory
[ERROR]  1: node::Abort() [node]
[ERROR]  2: 0x8c80076 [node]
[ERROR]  3: v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*) [node]
[ERROR]  4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node]
[ERROR]  5: v8::internal::Factory::NewMap(v8::internal::InstanceType, int, v8::i                       nternal::ElementsKind) [node]
[ERROR]  6: v8::internal::Map::RawCopy(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>,                        int) [node]
[ERROR]  7: v8::internal::Map::CopyDropDescriptors(v8::internal::Handle<v8::inte                       rnal::Map>) [node]
[ERROR]  8: v8::internal::Map::CopyReplaceDescriptors(v8::internal::Handle<v8::i                       nternal::Map>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::DescriptorArray>, v8::internal                       ::Handle<v8::internal::LayoutDescriptor>, v8::internal::TransitionFlag, v8::inte                       rnal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Name>, char const*, v8::internal::SimpleTransiti                       onFlag) [node]
[ERROR]  9: v8::internal::Map::CopyAddDescriptor(v8::internal::Handle<v8::intern                       al::Map>, v8::internal::Descriptor*, v8::internal::TransitionFlag) [node]
[ERROR] 10: v8::internal::Map::CopyWithConstant(v8::internal::Handle<v8::interna                       l::Map>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::inte                       rnal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::TransitionFlag) [                       node]
[ERROR] 11: v8::internal::Map::TransitionToDataProperty(v8::internal::Handle<v8:                       :internal::Map>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, v8::internal::Handle<                       v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::Object::S                       toreFromKeyed) [node]
[ERROR] 12: v8::internal::LookupIterator::PrepareTransitionToDataProperty(v8::in                       ternal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Objec                       t>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) [nod                       e]
[ERROR] 13: v8::internal::Object::AddDataProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*,                        v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v                       8::internal::Object::ShouldThrow, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) [node]
[ERROR] 14: v8::internal::JSObject::AddProperty(v8::internal::Handle<v8::interna                       l::JSObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, v8::internal::Handle<v8:                       :internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes) [node]
[ERROR] 15: v8::internal::Factory::NewFunction(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal                       ::String>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Code>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::in                       ternal::Object>, v8::internal::InstanceType, int, bool, bool, bool) [node]
[ERROR] 16: v8::internal::ApiNatives::CreateApiFunction(v8::internal::Isolate*,                        v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v                       8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::ApiNatives::ApiInstanceType) [node]
[ERROR] 17: 0x8554502 [node]
[ERROR] 18: v8::internal::ApiNatives::InstantiateFunction(v8::internal::Handle<v                       8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>) [node]
[ERROR] 19: v8::FunctionTemplate::GetFunction(v8::Local<v8::Context>) [node]
[ERROR] 20: v8::FunctionTemplate::GetFunction() [node]
[ERROR] 21: node::InitFs(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<                       v8::Context>, void*) [node]
[ERROR] 22: 0x8c858a0 [node]
[ERROR] 23: v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionC                       allbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)) [node]
[ERROR] 24: 0x85b3630 [node]
[ERROR] 25: 0x85b3dd0 [node]
[ERROR] 26: 0x4890a0fe
[ERROR] 27: 0x29d1d25d
[ERROR] 28: 0x4890b616
[ERROR] 29: 0x489384a8
[ERROR] 30: 0x48937d7f
[ERROR] 31: 0x29d1b14f
[ERROR] 32: 0x4890b616
[ERROR] 33: 0x489384a8
[ERROR] 34: 0x48937d7f
[ERROR] 35: 0x48937411
[ERROR] 36: 0x48936335
[ERROR] 37: 0x4893153e
[ERROR] 38: 0x48920a43
[ERROR] 39: v8::internal::Execution::Call(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::                       Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, int, v                       8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>*) [node]
[ERROR] 40: v8::Function::Call(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, int                       , v8::Local<v8::Value>*) [node]
[ERROR] 41: v8::Function::Call(v8::Local<v8::Value>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)                        [node]
[ERROR] 42: node::LoadEnvironment(node::Environment*) [node]
[ERROR] 43: node::Start(int, char**) [node]
[ERROR] 44: main [node]
[ERROR] 45: __libc_start_main [/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
[ERROR] Aborted (core dumped)
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 134.
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about th                       is command.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:09 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-14T19:58:35+13:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/74M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Someone has any help?

Regards,

-Rod

Comment: Using sudo should not be required and it's dangerous. Have you checked that /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/timetrack-jh/webpack/webpack.prod.js really does not exist?

Comment: Hi Gael. No, the directory ../webpack does not exist.

Comment: So either something went wrong during project generation or you did not commit all files to git. Compare with sample app: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-ng2

Comment: The problem persists. Now it came back to the original problem of out of heap memory on Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I again figured out the issue. When building on Linux machine and have out of heap memory on Javascript. Need to change that lines on package.json (only happened using JHipster with Angular 4):

"webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=5120 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
"webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=5120 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"

I updated the --max_old_space_size from 4096 to 5120 (1GB more).

That was it folks!

Thanks anyway for the good guys that helped me,

Best regards,

-Rod